# What is the purpose of `$[`in shell scripts?

Tags: shell, scripting

Looking for an easy way to make a random number, i came across a [web page](http://islandlinux.org/howto/generate-random-numbers-bash-scripting) that used the follow snip of code

```
  echo $[ ( $RANDOM % $DIE_SIDES )  + 1 ]
```

What is the purpose of the `$[`. Googling did not reveal the answer I seek. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`$[expression]`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.2) construct is used for arithmetic; `$[1+1]`, for example, returns 2. You can also say `$((expression))` or `expr 1 + 1`. The `expr` command version is old-school and should work in any shell, the `$[expression]` and `$((expression))` versions work in bash but I'm not sure if they're covered by POSIX.

**Update:** The `$[expression]` form is a bash extension, the [`$((expression))`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04) form is specified for the POSIX shell.

Comment: where is this bash extension documented? I can't find it in the man page.

Comment: @glenn: The only reference for it that I could find was [this one](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.2), the official documentation only seems to talk about the [`$((expression))`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#index-arithmetic-expansion-89) POSIX version. I'd guess that `$[expression]` is an artifact from before POSIX had `$(())` and it may be deprecated. Searching for `$[` doesn't do much good :)